# jquery href and onclick separation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code like this

```html
<a id="id101" href="javascript:func1();" onclick="return func2();">Link</a>
```

func2 returns true or false. Then, func1 is called only when function2 returns true. Right ?

In learning jquery, I found out that onclick is not good and depreciated, so I modified above code to

```html
<a id="id101" href="javascript:func1();">Link</a>
```

```js
jquery
$("#id101").click(func2() {
  //same stuffs from before which was in func2
});
```

Now, my question is:

after click handler is taken care of, what can I do with JavaScript inside href? Should I call func1 inside func2 in jQuery click handler of func2, when condition inside func2 is true? 
Or is there some elegant solution?

Also, Separating html and events code is good, but here this element with id `id101`can have many events associated with it, and in a large file, there might be so many html elements with many events. So, when I have a large page with many event handlers, then how can I better know which html element has which and how many events associated with it?

More explanation to above question as requested,

I meant id101 can have onclick, onmouseover, onmouseout and many other such events. There can be many such elements with many such event handlers. How do I better spot them ? In old style, all such event handlers are all placed together, like this

`<a id="id101" href="javascript:func1();" onclick="return func2();">Link</a>`.

I am not saying this is good, but atleast I can see that it has this onclick event. But now when separting this into jquery file, I have to search first this jquery file for id101 and then check events associated with it, which can be problem with html file having many elements and associated event handlers. Is there any better way to to find that information ?

Comment: Don't put JavaScript in the "href" at all.  Just do that (conditionally, if you want) in the event handler.

Comment: @endroix: As Pointy said, just remove the whole `href` attribute. Inline JS is bad news. And, when you bind with the jQuery selector, you have to use a '#' to indicate ID. Right now your jQuery is most likely doing nothing. Change it to `$("#id101").click();`, and remove that whole `href="x"`.

Comment: @Josh, I forgot that #. Now updated

Answer (score 10):

If I understand correctly, you want to avoid the inline Javascript, but you also want to be able to glance at an `a` and know if it has an event bound to it. Unfortunately, there isn't an acceptable way to denote this, as inline Javascript is bad news. Perhaps you can just give your element a dummy class to aid your future readability. Other than that, forget the whole `func1` and `func2` thing. Just use an anonymous function inside of your click binding.

```
<a id="some_id" class="optional_has_click">Click Me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#some_id").click(function(){

      // do something
      alert( $(this).attr("id") );

    });

  });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Also, removing the `href` will remove the visual cue, so you can use your dummy class to make it look like an `a`.

Here is a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/zzTSt/1/

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid inline JS but also see events associated with `a`. What if I have to use this func1 and func2 in many places, can I do this with anonymous function ?

Comment: @endroix: Just call the function inside of the anonymous one, where I'm alerting right now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I recommend you to write func1 inside func2.
HTML:

```
<a id="id101" href="#" >Link</a>
```

jQuery

```
$("#id101").click(func2() {
   var status = false;
   //func2 goes here and modifies status value.
   if (status) {
       // func1 goes here
   } else {
       // in case if status is false.
   }

});
```

Also I didn't get what you mean in second part of your question, could you please be more specific.

Comment: In fact theoretically there is no limit on events and handlers. Just create handlers for them. I think you could use classes instead of ids. if there are a lot of links that should have javascript handlers, try to gather them. like `<a href="#" class="function_1_class">Link</a>
<a href="#" class="function_2_class">Link 2</a>` Also if you'll need  to do specific work on all question, I recommend you to use another attribute which will identify which link was clicked. 
`<a href="#" class="some_class" my_unique_id="q4Rf9"` and get this attribute with `.attr()`

Comment: and if you don't want your page "hopping" to the top by clicking this link (because it refers to "#"), you could possibly use something like `<span id="id101">Link</span>` instead. just style this span that it looks like a link.

Comment: @otta : Yes, I have read using # in href is bad. Using in span and styling is nice solution.

Comment: @VahagnMkrtchyan I didnt understand importance of using my_unique_id. What plus it gives than using normal id ?

Comment: @odaa, or return `false` from the handler to prevent the default action, i.e., hopping to the top.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can tell you is that this is "smelly" code--you don't want your javascript all over the place like this.  I would recommend you spend a few more hours learning some jQuery fundamentals and move on from there.  I know it can be frustrating, especially if you are working with legacy javascript.